Constructing Linked List in Rust from head to tail without unwrap
It is said that unwrap is unsafe and it should be avoided if possible.
While I was constructing a linked list, I found an unwrap inevitable.
My question is, is it possible to remove this unwrap or is there any theoretical reason that it is not possible?
(Updated the code to be an MRE for future reference.)
pub struct Node {
    pub value: i32,
    pub next: Option<Box<Node>>
}

impl Node {
    fn new(value: i32) -> Self {
        Node { next: None, value }
    }
}

fn vector_to_linked_list(v: &Vec<i32>) -> Option<Box<Node>> {
    let mut sentinel: Box<Node> = Box::new(Node {
        value: -1,
        next: None,
    });
    let mut current: &mut Box<Node> = &mut sentinel;
    for value in v.iter() {
        current.next = Some(Box::new(Node {
            value: *value,
            next: None,
        }));
        current = current.next.as_mut().unwrap();
    }
    sentinel.next
}

fn main() {
    let v: Vec<i32> = vec! [1, 2, 3];
    vector_to_linked_list(&v);
}

I am not expecting an answer which adds a meaningless branch like let-else or if-let.
Note: For the other way around, it seems that replace is useful.
self.root = Some(Box::new(Node {
    value: value,
    next: ::std::mem::replace(&mut self.root, None),
}));


You should definitely avoid .unwrap() if at all possible since it could cause a panic, but "unsafe" has specific meaning in Rust (meaning something could cause memory errors) and .unwrap() is not unsafe.

Thanks for your comment. It helped me a lot. I mainly write in C++ and Python and quite new to Rust. While I was teaching programming, one of my students wrote this and I felt it was not the best way.

You haven't posted an MRE so I can't verify whether this passes the borrow checker (I think it will), but this is exactly the kind of scenario where you would want to use Option::insert, which sets the Option to Some using the provided value, then returns an exclusive reference to that value:
current = current.next.insert(Box::new(Node {
    value: value,
    next: None,
}));

I would prefer this since it's cleaner, but if your concern is that your code is less efficient or could panic at runtime, note that the optimizer will realize that the None case is impossible and elide the check and the panicking branch.  In a simple contrived case comparing the two approaches using optimization level 1, the generated assembly is identical.

Thanks, this worked perfectly for me. Also, I updated the code to be an MRE. By the way, is there a good way to find this function?

@KeitaODA I'm not sure what you mean. I linked to the documentation in my answer.

I really know nothing about Rust. Actually, the MRE is my very first Rust code in my life. I teach programming to those who want to be SWEs, and some of my students ask me to review codes in Rust. I know other languages, so I can point out something is redundant, but I still have some trouble telling best practices. I wish there is a good codebase or documents that have clean and tidy ways of writing Rust.

@KeitaODA I would just read the documentation top-to-bottom for many of the common built-in types, like Option and Result. That's how I learned about a lot of the little helpful utilities. I may not remember their names, but I remember that they exist, which is more important, because I can always look up the name if I know it exists.

@cdhowie Thank you very much. Coincidently, "Read the documentation" is also what I always tell my students, and I totally agree with its importance. I have to keep in mind that there is no royal road to learning.
